# VB.NET- Changing .Text property of Textbox throws Null Reference Exception

Tags: nullreferenceexception, vb.net-2010

This MUST be trivial. I do this for a living and CAN NOT figure out why I am getting this exception:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   Message=Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim counties() As String

    counties = {"", "Huntsville, AL", "Madison, AL", "Rural Madison County, AL", "Taft, TN"}
    Me.cbCounties.DataSource = counties

    Me.lblStatus.Text = "[ Please select a county ]"
    Me.lblStatus.Left = Me.ClientSize.Width \ 2 - Me.lblStatus.Width \ 2



End Sub

Private Sub cbCounties_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbCounties.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case cbCounties.SelectedIndex
        Case 1
            txtTaxRate.Text = "8.00%" 'Issue is these, when index is changed.
        Case 2
            txtTaxRate.Text = "8.50%"
        Case 3
            txtTaxRate.Text = "5.50"
        Case 4
            txtTaxRate.Text = "9.50%"
        Case Else
            txtTaxRate.Text = Nothing
    End Select

    Me.lblStatus.Text = "[ Please enter net amount ]"
    Me.lblStatus.Left = Me.ClientSize.Width \ 2 - Me.lblStatus.Width \ 2

End Sub
```

End Class

Help?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: See comment inside of code. Specifically, it is thrown inside of the select case statement, referring to the txtTaxRate TextBox

Comment: Is this after you changed it a couple of times? setting txtTaxRate = Nothing and later trying to set txtTaxRate.Text to something else will cause some problems. try changing txtTaxRate = Nothing to txtTaxRate.Text = ""

Comment: Alright... that was it. Make this an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this after you changed it a couple of times?

Setting `txtTaxRate = Nothing` and later trying to set `txtTaxRate.Text` to something else will cause some problems.

You are setting the textbox object to nothing, and later trying to reference one of its properties.

Try changing

`txtTaxRate = Nothing`

to

```
txtTaxRate.Text = ""
```